# Can I integrate JIRA Issue with Gitlab Issue for Git commits, Merge requests, create branch when I am not admin in JIRA?

Tags: gitlab, jira

I am not admin user to JIRA but have admin rights to Gitlab. Can I integrate JIRA Issue with Gitlab Issue for Git commits, Merge requests, create branch. I know that all these are available when I have admin rights in JIRA using "Gitlab Integration with Gitlab" addin and configuring JIRA in Gitlab.
I have done POC for Integration for all this and sync for issues from JIRA to Gitlab and vice versa but but when I am Jira Admin user Is there any way around?
Any addin or plugin or configuration used without any cost?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an Jira account, that can write to the projects. You need the account username and password, and the ID of the task change to work.

If you are not a Jira admin, and you do not have access to such account, you will either have to talk with your system administrator, or give up.